# Using full stop in letter format

Tags: punctuation

Do we need to use full stop after city while addressing a letter and after name?

E.g.

> No.3, Mane Road,
>   London.

or

> Yours lovingly,
>   John.

Comment: No, because it should be "London (postal code)" and below that "United Kingdom".

Answer (score 1):

This one is fairly easy, I went to Google. On the envelope after the city some use a comma and some use no punctuation.[image: envelope]

In the body of the letter: [image: body of letter]

[LINK](https://www.scribendi.com/advice/how_to_write_a_formal_letter.en.html)

I have never seen a full stop after the writer's name.

Comment: It's worth noting that the first line of your **123 Elm Ave.** example ends in a full stop (the othographic feature OP is specifically asking about) - but this is ***only*** because ***Ave*** is an abbreviation of ***Avenue.*** I'd also point out that many writers (particularly, *older* people) would put a comma at the end of each line except the last one, AND that people differ as to whether they include a comma *within* a line - to separate, for example, *house number* from *road name* (where again, older people are more likely to do this).